# Why is read_xlsx reading in stale values from a different excel spreadsheet?

Tags: r, openxlsx, readxl

Given the nature of this question, I can't really give a fully reproducible example.  But here is the nature of the issue:

1. I have spreadsheets in a folder
2. I used openxlsx package and wrote a script to write a new formula in a different part of the spreadsheet, and to write "YES" in cell B1.  When this happens, the Revenue line updates in the spreadsheet (using an `if` excel formula).  A version 2 of the file is then saved with the changes.
3. So far so good.
4. I then used readxl to read the financials of both spreadsheets in the directory
5. The problem comes in when I look at the results.  The financials in `company_a2` (the updated file after running the script), the result after step 2, are being read in as the same as `company_a` even though they are different numbers.

I will put the code in case that reveals something obvious I am missing, as well as a couple of screen shots of the output

The code:

```
# ===========================================================================================
# Load packages
Library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx
library(readxl)



# Set working directory to excel folder location
setwd("C:/Users/davem/Sync/R files/excel_file_test")


# Create function to write formulas and data in excel file
edit_xl_fx <- function(input_wb, input_sheet, input_formula, input_data, start_row_form, start_col_form, start_row_data, start_col_data){
  
  
  # Load
  wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(input_wb)
  
  
  # Write
  formula_cols <- LETTERS[4:8]
  
  lapply(1:length(formula_cols), FUN = function(x) writeFormula(wb, input_sheet, x = input_formula[x], startCol = formula_cols[x], startRow = start_row_form))
  writeData(wb, sheet = input_sheet, x = input_data, startCol = start_col_data, startRow = start_row_data)
  
  
  # Save
  orig_xl_name <- str_remove(input_wb, pattern = ".xlsx")
  new_xl_name <- paste0(orig_xl_name, 2, ".xlsx")
  
  saveWorkbook(wb, new_xl_name, overwrite = TRUE)
}



# Get list of files
xl_files <- as.list(list.files(pattern = ".xlsx"))

# Run function
lapply(
  xl_files,
  edit_xl_fx,
  input_sheet = "Sheet1",
  input_formula = c(
    "D21/(D20-D16)",
    "E21/(E20-E16)",
    "F21/(F20-F16)",
    "G21/(G20-G16)",
    "H21/(H20-H16)"
  ),
  input_data     = "YES",
  start_row_form = 26,
  start_col_form = 4:8,
  start_row_data = 1,
  start_col_data = 2
)
```

This all works.  But then when I go to extract the financials, I get the same results even thought the values in the files are different.

**Values in the excel files:**
[image]

Code to read the files:

```
 # Get updated list of files
xl_files_updated <- as.list(list.files(pattern = ".xlsx"))


# Create function to read in files
financials <- lapply(xl_files_updated, function(x) read_excel(path = x, sheet = "Sheet1", range = "B10:H21")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.) %>% 
  mutate(across(
    .cols = is.numeric,
    .fns = round, 1
  )
  )
```

Data that is read into R:
[image]

Even if I just run `readxl::read_xlsx(path = "company_a2.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", range = "B10:H21")` I still get the numbers in **company_**a****.xlsx as opposed to the updated numbers.

Thanks for helping clear up what I am missing here!

Comment: I'm pretty sure any field calculated with a formula wont update until you open and save the excel file. When you replace the value with "Yes", the value is updated but the formulas won't recalculate without opening the workbook.

Comment: Ah, that is indeed it Mako212.  Once I opened and saved it worked.  Is there an easy way to automate around that?  Or does excel literally have to launch for each file?

Comment: Ideally, I'd recommend performing the calculation in R on those values that "Yes" affects. You might be able to call a VBscript from R to recalculate, there's a few threads on the issue if you search on SO, but better to avoid it all together if you can.